# Why does my score getter evaluate to NaN when the computation by itself returns a number?

Tags: javascript, nan

I am building a simple N-back game as a little project. The game keeps track of matches in each session, as well as the matches the player gets and then shows the player their score as a percentage after each session. However, for some reason my score method is returning NaN even though if I run the computation inside the getter, I get a number.

This is the score method:

```
get score() { return Math.round(((this.player_matches / this.matches) * 100) 
- (this.error_count * 3)); }
```

At the end of each session, the score displays as 0 because I have written the method to update the score for the user to display 0 by default if the score is not a valid number:

```
update_score()
  {
    if (isNaN(this.score)
    {
      $('#score-output').text(0);
    }
    else {
      $('#score-output').text(this.score);
    }
  }
```

Both this.matches and this.player_matches are valid numbers. Yet if I open the console and type game.score (I have an instance of my class as game) it returns NaN, but if I type Math.round(((game.player_matches / game.matches) * 100) - (game.error_count * 3)); I do get a number.

This is incredibly frustrating. I cannot understand why the computation inside the function block evaluates correctly but when called as a function it doesn't. If anyone has any suggestions or if you want to see any more of the code let me know. Thanks.

Comment: How is `update_score()` called? What is the value of `this` when it runs?

Comment: if (isNaN(this.score))- you forgot to close the if condition. I am not sure if this might help you

Comment: @MonicaAcha that must just be a transcription error because the code would fail with a syntax error before it was able to get `NaN`.

Comment: As I explained, the update_score method prints out the score to the web page. If this is NaN then it prints 0. It is called at the end of each game session. But the real problem is with the score getter.

Comment: You do not know that the problem is with the getter. If `this` in `update_score()` is not a reference to your object, then `this.score` will be `undefined` and `isNaN()` will return `true`.

Comment: I shouldnt have even included the update_score method. The problem is the getter. It returns NaN even though the function body does a valid calculation on valid numbers.

Comment: Verifying that `this` is what you think it is would conclusively determine that something about the getter is wrong. For example, if you've explicitly set up `game.update_score` as an event handler incorrectly, that would cause the behavior.

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating that your code works *if* the `update_score()` method is simply called as a method of the object (`game`).](https://jsfiddle.net/buh30zya/)

Comment: @Pointy I am very confused now, because I do call the `update_score()` method as a method of the object. There is nothing different about how you have called it, except that I use ES6 and define it as a method of the class `Game` and then instantiate it as `game` rather than defining it as a method of an object literal.

Comment: Well you haven't posted how exactly you call the `update_score()` so it's hard to say exactly what's going wrong. Have you added a `console.log()` to the getter to verify that it's being called? If it isn't, then that implies `this` in `update_score()` is not a reference to an instance of the class.

Comment: I am pasting a dropbox link here so others can look at the whole thing.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e667ecvxk7gn0bt/AABDp2o77cMagdhqCnY2QzJOa?dl=0